# Error publishing in RPubs from RStudio:

Tags: r

I am trying to publishing a document from RStudio to RPubs, but keep getting the following error:

```
**Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
 Failed to connect to api.rpubs.com port 443: Timed out
 Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
 Execution halted**
```

Not sure why connection keeps terminating to API for RPubs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It basically says that it cannot connect to `api.rpubs.com`. Perhaps the site is down or there may be a connection blocking issue on your end. Check your firewall for example. Are you using a proxy? Etc.